# CiviCRM 4.6.2 extra components in menu

Tags: civicase, civicrm-home

I just installed drupal 7 and then civiCRM on Linux Mint 17.1 in a VirtualBox

Install went smoothly.

I am only using CiviCASE and CiviReports moduals. Unfortunately, there are still menu items for Mailings and Campaigns.

Mailings and Campaigns are disabled components in my setup. The picture below shows the extra menu items and my list of enabled components.

[image: Extra menu items]

I tried enabling/save/disabling but nothing got rid of those two menu items. The other component menu items did go away.

[edit] Here's what the drop down menu looks like for the extraneous Mailing menu item, as requested.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is it a bug, a feature or easily fixed?

Thanks in advance for any help!

John in Oregon

Answer (score 3):

There's a semi-documented "menu rebuild" commands that will probably help here. From your CiviCRM base URL, go to `/menu/rebuild`  e.g. on Drupal with Clean URLs, http://example.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild. Follow that with `/cache/clear` if necessary!

Comment: Nothing changed using /menu/rebuild followed by /cache/clear.

Should I report a bug do you think?

Comment: Just reinstalled drupal and civicrm 4.63 and still had Mailings but not Campaigns show in the menu after removing them both.

Comment: Hmm - I actually fixed the Campaigns bug, but didn't personally experience the Mailings bug.  Could you please take a screenshot of your Mailing menu in a dropped-down state?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the Campaigns bug. I edited the original post to include the screen shot of the Mailings drop down list.

Comment: Ha - seeing the photo, I realize I was confused - I fixed a different menu bug, the A/B testing not appearing. I can look at what you're seeing though.

Answer (score 1):

The campaigns menu seems to behave now, but I was able to reproduce this for mailings and I agree it's a bug. I recommend filing a bug report on the issue tracker. More information about filing issues can be found at https://civicrm.org/issue-queue